# Closed Distinct Items by Current and Previous Year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have the PBI measure below to calculate closed distinct Items based on if they have a date in the Closed Date column. However, I would like to turn the card visual to a KPI and compare the Closed Template Total to Closed Template Total this time last year. Instead of same period last year, I would need the measures to compare the value of closed templates from January-November this year to January-November last year (which I have for another measure without the DISTINCT COUNT, so I have been struggling to combine both).

Current Measure Counting Distinct Templates Closed:

```
Closed Temps =
CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT(Activities[Template_ID]),
            ( Activities[Close_Date] ) )
```

I would like to Update to have a dynamic Current Year Measure and a Previous Year Measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Closed Temps YTD = CALCULATE(
    [Closed Temps],
    DATESYTD(Activities[Close_Date]) 
  )

Closed Temps PY YTD = CALCULATE(
    [Closed Temps],
    PREVIOUSYEAR( DATESYTD(Activities[Close_Date]) )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! I switched the Close_date to actual Date column and it worked.